# It is possible to redirect website visitors to a main entrance page even if they have specific webpages bookmarked?

Tags: iis

I manage an internal web-based application that is deployed through IIS and accessed using IE. The 'recommended' path to accessing the application is:

1. Open company Intranet homepage and click the URL that points to the homepage of the website I manage
2. My homepage contains various need-to-know information and the direct link to the web-app's login page
3. They visit the login page, log into the application and start using it.

Users can easily add the URL of the app's login page to their bookmarks so they can access it faster. But I intend on adding more features to my homepage such as blog updates, links to help directories, supporting documentation etc. I want to ensure everyone is both aware of and will not ignore these.

Is there some way for me make sure if anyone tries to visit the direct login webpage, my website forcibly redirects them to the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `referer` header. For example:

Your homepage is `http://www.example.com/`

Login page is `http://www.example.com/login`

In your web.config you need to add this rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="redirect to home without referer" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^login$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="http://www.example.com" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/" />
</rule>
```

This rule will redirect to homepage, if your visitors will open login page by direct link. It will not redirect if they opened login page from any page of your website